# altering Visual Studio's Clean Solution option

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

As a post-build event for some of my projects, I have documentation copied from directories like bin\Project\Debug to a central doc\ directory in the root directory of my solution.  When I do a Clean Solution, I know bin\ and obj\ files get deleted, but I would like for another event to happen to delete cruft from my own doc\ directory.  Is there a way I can hook into the Clean Solution event to run my own post-clean code?  Perhaps a macro?  I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Team System.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this blog post (and the one it links to) for what you're after http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2005/11/23/496396.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This topic is well covered in 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724(v=vs.80).aspx